# How to schedule a Jenkins Job dynamically based on the time value in database

Tags: jenkins, scheduling

I have a situation where there is a database in which a table consists of scheduled time to build.
This schedule time to build may vary from day to day.
Say for example,

```
Today the entry in db is 09/01/2020 5:00 PM 
Tomorrow the entry can be 10/01/2020 4:00 PM
```

So, based on the above table, I need to schedule a Jenkins job today at 5:00 PM and tomorrow at 4:00 PM
Is there any possibility in Jenkins to configure the build based on the above table entries.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question belongs to devops.stackexchange.com

Comment: thanks, will post there as well :)